# Android: how to draw borders when I click my view

Tags: android

I have some views like:

```
private class MyViewCircle extends View {

        public MyViewCircle(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);
        }

    }
```

And add to my LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout img01 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.img01);
img01.addView(myViewCircle);
```

From my XML

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:background="#C07BD1"
                       android:id="@+id/img01"/>
```

If I click this view I want to generate borders (means user select this view). If user click again the border will disappear. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) drawable? Basically what you do is make two circles, one without the border and one with the border. Then use the StateList to tell the LinearLayout which one to use under certain conditions (i.e. clicked and not clicked).